# Adding multiple overlays to MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am having some trouble understanding how to add multiple overlays to MKMapView.

I have an array routes tracked. The routes tracked are arrays of CLLocations. So I have an array of arrays.

I am able to take one route and draw it on the map view. However, I need to draw ALL the routes onto the map view.

So here is how I go about creating the MKPolyline for 1 route:

```
-(void) loadRoute
{
    //So we grab an array that holds all the locations of one route. 
            NSArray *locations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[routesArray objectAtIndex:0]];

            // while we create the route points, we will also be calculating the bounding box of our route
            // so we can easily zoom in on it. 
            MKMapPoint northEastPoint; 
            MKMapPoint southWestPoint; 

            // create a c array of points. 
            MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) *[locations count]);

            for(int idx = 0; idx < [locations count]; idx++)
            {
                CLLocation *tempLoc = (CLLocation*)[locations objectAtIndex:idx];

                CLLocationDegrees latitude  = tempLoc.coordinate.latitude;
                CLLocationDegrees longitude = tempLoc.coordinate.longitude;

                // create our coordinate and add it to the correct spot in the array 
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

                MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);

                // if it is the first point, just use them, since we have nothing to compare to yet. 
                if (idx == 0) {
                    northEastPoint = point;
                    southWestPoint = point;
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (point.x > northEastPoint.x) 
                        northEastPoint.x = point.x;
                    if(point.y > northEastPoint.y)
                        northEastPoint.y = point.y;
                    if (point.x < southWestPoint.x) 
                        southWestPoint.x = point.x;
                    if (point.y < southWestPoint.y) 
                        southWestPoint.y = point.y;
                }
                pointArr[idx] = point;
            }


            self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:[locations count]];

//Zoom in to fit route on screen
            _routeRect = MKMapRectMake(southWestPoint.x, southWestPoint.y, northEastPoint.x - southWestPoint.x, northEastPoint.y - southWestPoint.y);

            // clear the memory allocated earlier for the points
            free(pointArr);

}
```

Here is the MapKit delegate call that returns the overlay:

```
#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        //if we have not yet created an overlay view for this overlay, create it now. 
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;
        }
        overlayView = self.routeLineView;
    }

    return overlayView;
}
```

So all the code given above works fine. I can't figure out how to load more overlays to show the other routes.

I thought that maybe in loadRoute method, running through all the routes and creating a MKOverlayView for each one. Storing all those MKOverlayView in an array then doing: 
[self.mapView addOverlays:array];

But it doesn't work. The problem is that in the delegate method I somehow need to know which overlay to return.

So if I could do something along the lines of:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    int tag = overlay.tag;
    return (MKOverlayView*)[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:tag];
}
```

it would work fine. But unfortunately it doesn't work like that :(

Any help would be very much appreciated!

EDIT:

I use this in ViewDidLoad to add the overlay:

```
[self loadRoute];

        // add the overlay to the map
        if (nil != self.routeLine) {
            [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
        }

        // zoom in on the route. 
        [self zoomInOnRoute];
```

This is in the header:

```
// the data representing the route points. 
    MKPolyline* _routeLine;

    // the view we create for the line on the map
    MKPolylineView* _routeLineView;

    // the rect that bounds the loaded points
    MKMapRect _routeRect;
```

Comment: What are `self.routeLine` and `self.routeLineView` used for _besides_ in the code shown above?  Show the code where you call addOverlay or addOverlays.

Comment: So routeLine and routeLineView are not used anywhere besides in the code shown in the question, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `routeLine` and `routeLineView` variables can only point to one overlay and overlay view at a time so you would theoretically need an array of such variables.

However, based on the code shown, you don't need to keep references to these in the first place.

I suggest removing the `routeLine` and `routeLineView` variables.

Then you just create an overlay object locally and in `viewForOverlay` return a view for the requested `overlay` parameter.

In the `loadRoute` method, you can loop through the `routesArray` and for each route, create a local overlay object, and call `addOverlay` on it.

There's also an easier way to construct a map rect that bounds all the routes so you can set the map's region to show them all.

Example:

```
-(void) loadRoute
{
    _routeRect = MKMapRectNull;

    for (int raIndex = 0; raIndex < routesArray.count; raIndex++) 
    {
        //So we grab an array that holds all the locations of one route. 
        NSArray *locations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                                 [routesArray objectAtIndex:raIndex]];
        //note we are getting object at raIndex (not 0) above

        //...no change to existing code here...

        //self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:[locations count]];
        //replace above line with this...
        MKPolyline *pl = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:[locations count]];
        [mapView addOverlay:pl];

        //Zoom in to fit route on screen
        //_routeRect = MKMapRectMake(southWestPoint.x, southWestPoint.y, northEastPoint.x - southWestPoint.x, northEastPoint.y - southWestPoint.y);
        //replace above line with this to create a rect around ALL routes...
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(_routeRect))
            _routeRect = pl.boundingMapRect;
        else
            _routeRect = MKMapRectUnion(_routeRect, pl.boundingMapRect);

        // clear the memory allocated earlier for the points
        free(pointArr);
    }    
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`, just call `loadRoute` and don't call `addOverlay`.

The `viewForOverlay` method becomes much simpler:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *pv = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    pv.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    pv.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    pv.lineWidth = 3;
    return pv;
}
```

By the way, in `loadRoute`, this line:

```
MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) *[locations count]);
```

should be:

```
MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(MKMapPoint) *[locations count]);
```

It should use the size of `MKMapPoint` (not `CLLocationCoordinate2D`).
They are not the same thing (even though the structs happen to be the same byte size).